# add 1 Hour to field in sql

Tags: mysql

i have the following Field in my database.
[Field value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sezRD.png)
[Database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RNoP.png)

We now want to add 1 Hour to this Field for the complete SQL Table.
Any help is hightly appreciated.

MySQL -> 4.5.4

Comment: @Shadow, This is not a duplicate since the addtime() function is not working as expected here. `ADDTIME('23:15', '01:00') -> 24:15`, what is that?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson just because you do not understand how the time datatype works, does not mean that the duplicate is incorrect.

Comment: @Shadow In what way do I not understand the time datatype? Are you saying 24:15 is a correct time? Could you please elaborate instead of just writing snarky comments?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes, it is a correct time value. Btw, which part of the question describes how to handle such cases, so that you could say 24:15 is incorrect?

Comment: @Shadow, yes I just realised that it is not clear if we are talking about time of day or elapsed time here. I was only thinking about this as being time of day hence my objection to 24:15 being a correct time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please use below query to update the deptime as:

```
UPDATE table_name SET deptime = ADDTIME(deptime, '01:00') ;
```

Replace **table_name** with your table name.

Comment: Hello @Suresh thanks for your Answer. I get this failure message: #1267 - Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '<>' For that i changed the structure to utf8_general_ci, But now this code adds also seconds to my file. is that avoidable? –

Comment: @thomasha91: please share your table structure.

Comment: I found a solution for me... I just set the maximum length to 5 digits so seconds can't be set

Comment: @thomasha91 : please accept the answer if it solve your query.